# Multiple routing parameters with view model in asp .net mvc

Tags: c#, seo, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, viewmodel

I am trying to experiment with routing and generate a seo-friendly url for searches.

Currently I have viewmodel as below:

```
public class SearchFormViewModel
    {
        //[Required(ErrorMessage="Keyword is required")]
        public string Keyword { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TransactionTypes { get; set; }
        public int TransactionTypeId { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RoomLookUps { get; set; }
        public int? MinBeds { get; set; }
        public int? MaxBeds { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

When this form gets submitted it goes to a controller:

```
    public ActionResult SearchProperties(SearchFormViewModel viewModelInp)
    {
         // Perform search;
    }
```

and the search results are displayed. However, the url that gets generated is as follows:

```
http://localhost:49191/search/searchproperties?Keyword=London&TransactionTypeId=2&MinBeds=&MaxBeds=&MinPrice=&MaxPrice=
```

I require a URL which looks like

```
http://localhost:49191/flats-to-rent/London?MinBeds=&MaxBeds=&MinPrice=&MaxPrice=
```

I am not sure how to pass the parameters from ViewModel to Route

the following route doesn't work:

```
routes.MapRouteLowercase(
                "Search-Properties-Buy",
                "flats-to-rent/{Keyword}",
                new { controller = "Search", action = "SearchProperties", Keyword = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new { TransactionTypeId = "2" }
            );
```

I have tried various other things but none of it seems to work and I get a 404 error.

I am unable to find any example which might help me.

Comment: When submitted, form data is serialized and sent to the server. In this case you are not using ASP.NET MVC Routing. Your URL is correct but never work with client data. I suppose that "the url that gets generated is as follow" is generated after submit button pressed.

Comment: You are correct. Is there a way to create URL that I require?

Comment: You need to override, client side, your submit button pressed event, and build string that must be submitted. There's no another way to do this. Let me know, you are doing a POST or GET request to the server?

Comment: Hi Roberto, it is a GET request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I try to give you a solution.
Place an input field that contains a base route generated by asp.net mvc:

```
<input type="hidden" value="@Url.Action("SearchProperties", new { Keyword = "{Prototype}" })" id="BaseSearchURL" />
```

As you can see, I've specified a Keyword with "{Prototype}" value, this instruct asp.net mvc to provide your configured custom route, and, after render, in the page HTML you should see something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="server/flats-to-rent/{Prototype}" id="BaseSearchURL" />
```

After, you can use jquery to override the submit button pressed event and you can write custom code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=submit]').submit(function() {
        var baseURL = $('#BaseSearchURL').val();
        var keyword = $('input[name=Keyword]');
        var action = baseURL.replace('{Prototype}', keyword);
        var form = $(this).parents('form');
        // Get all parameter except Keyword
        var params = $('input[name!=Keyword], select, textarea', form).serialize();
        action += "?" + params;
        document.location = action;
    });
});
```

Steps are easy:

- Get routing template form previous generated
- Get keyword that must be replaceted to "{Prototype}";
- Get form parameters and append these to the action
- Invoke document.location to start specific URL.